# network managers on Ubuntu 14.04 and Ubuntu Mate 16.04 differ

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, network-manager

I am building an ad hoc network to share data between a Dell lap-top running Ubuntu 14.04 and a Raspberry Pi 3 (RP) running Ubuntu Mate 16.04.  Before the inclusion of the RP, two ordinary lap-tops ran fine.  I have to temporarily disable the network manager in order to take control of one of the lan devices.

On the lap-tops, sudo stop network-manager works fine, leaving the devices on, but on the RP3, it says 'no such command: stop'.  I searched for analternative, and found:
    sudo /etc/init.d/network-manager stop
(and start).  These work on the RP, but are much more draconian - completely removing the lan device I want to manage.
Can anyone suggest a gentler way to stop the network manager on Ubuntu 16.04, please?

Comment: I believe it is: `sudo service network-manager stop`

Answer (score 0):

OK, I blundered around on my Google sleigh and stumbled across this which works in both worlds:

```
sudo service network-manager stop / start
```